# Android studio canot resolve symbol and will not compile

Tags: java, android

my code will not compile and i cannot figure out how to fix it.The variables addWhippedCream and addChocolate are giving me an error when i try to pass them into the calculatePrice method from in the orderSummary method. I have tried making them global variables but that produces a run time error

```
  package com.example.android.justjava;

  import android.graphics.Color;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.CheckBox;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  import java.text.NumberFormat;

  /**
    * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
    */
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}



/**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    int price=5;

    EditText Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_view);
    int total=calculatePrice(price, addWhippedCream, addChocolate);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkBox);
    CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Chocolate_checkBox);
    boolean addWhippedCream=checkBox.isChecked();
    boolean addChocolate=checkBox2.isChecked();
    String customerName= Name.getText().toString();
    displayMessage (createOrderSummary(total,addWhippedCream,addChocolate,customerName));
}


int quantity = 2;
public void increment(View view){

    quantity = quantity + 1;
    if (quantity==100){
        return;
    }
    displayQuantity(quantity);
}

public void decrement (View view){

    quantity = quantity - 1;

    if (quantity==1) {
        return;
    }
    displayQuantity(quantity);
}



/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
private void displayQuantity(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}
/**
 * This method displays the given text on the screen.
 */
private void displayMessage(String message) {
    TextView orderSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order_summary_text_view);
    orderSummaryTextView.setText(message);
    orderSummaryTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}

private int calculatePrice(int price, boolean addWhippedCream, boolean addChocolate){
     int total = quantity * price;

    if (addWhippedCream){
        total=total+1;
    }

    if (addChocolate) {
        total=total+2;
    }
    return total;
}

/*creates orderSummary
*
* takes in int total, boolean isChecked, boolean isChecked2, String customerName
*
* @returns orderSummary
*/
private String createOrderSummary(int total, boolean addWhippedCream, boolean addChocolate, String customerName){
   String orderSummary = "Name: " + customerName +
           "\nAdd whipped cream? " + addWhippedCream +
           "\nAdd chocolate? " + addChocolate +
           "\nQuantity: " + quantity +
           "\nTotal: $" + total +
           "\nThank you!";
    return orderSummary;
}


}
```

Comment: You have called the method calculatePrice(price, addWhippedCream, addChocolate) before declaring the addWhippedCream and addChocolate variables. Just call the method after declaring both the boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare variables before you use them. You have

```
int total=calculatePrice(price, addWhippedCream, addChocolate);
//code
boolean addWhippedCream=checkBox.isChecked();
boolean addChocolate=checkBox2.isChecked();
```

But you want to switch the declaration to before the call

```
boolean addWhippedCream=checkBox.isChecked();
boolean addChocolate=checkBox2.isChecked();
int total=calculatePrice(price, addWhippedCream, addChocolate);
```

Comment: i did that but now my checkboxes won't change state

Comment: @enverbrowne Use a debugger, step through your code line by line. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html